# Run-time error '424': Object required error

Tags: excel, vba

I am brand new to VBA and I am trying to learn by doing. 
While following a step by step Youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-yQf2Kiu6Y) on how to create a user form that feeds to a database, I have encountered the below error. 
I would appreciate any kind of guidance. Thank you!

I keep getting the

> "Run-time error '424': Object required"

on the forth line of code.

---

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = iDatabase 'error here

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtExpense.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtType.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtPeriod.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtDate.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtAmount.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 5).Value = txtComment.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is iDatabase defined?

Comment: Unless `iDatabase` has some kind of Global or Public scope, your code does not know what it is.

Comment: Is `iDatabase` the name of the sheet? If yes, the command should be: `wks = Sheets("iDatabase")`

Comment: Youtube is a horrible place to learn how to write code. It's usually very outdated, and that particular one is from 2018.